# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.views.hello'; 'myapp.views' is not a package

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model-view-controller, django-views

I'm using django 2.0.2 to develop a simple web app. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. I'm getting the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.views.hello'; 'myapp.views' is not a package
```

Here is my code for

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def hello(request):
   return render(request,'myapp/templates/hello.html',{})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include('myapp.views.hello'), name='hello'),
]
```

Throwing the same error even when I did `from myapp.views import *`

What is wrong with my code?

Here's the tree structure

```
DjProject/
├── db.sqlite3
├── DjProject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── myapp
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   └── hello.html
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py

7 directories, 22 files
```

Comment: That's not how `include` works... just `import views` and use `views.hello`.

Comment: Please post the tree structure of your project here.

Comment: @internet_user I tried as u said. This is the output.


`File "/home/sukumar/PycharmProjects/DjProject/DjProject/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('hello/', 'views.hello', name='hello'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Django documentation regarding the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#include) function:

> include()
>
> A function that takes a full Python import path to another URLconf
> module that should be “included” in this place.

This means that when using `include` you're supposed to supply it a separate `urls.py` located within your app. In your example this would mean that you have to create a new `urls.py` under the `myapp` Django app.

If you do not require a separate `urls.py`, you can simply import the desired view:

```
from myapp.views import hello as myapp_hello
```

and then use it like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', myapp_hello),
]
```

Comment: Glad I could have been of help @Ssukumar.